# How to join attributes in sql select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join few attributes in select statement as one for example

```
select id, (name + ' ' + surname + ' ' + age) as info from users
```

this doesn't work, how to do it?
I'm using postgreSQL.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? What's the question?

Comment: What's the question?  What happens when you tried the above?  What database server are you  using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres uses `||` to [concatenate strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html); your query needs to be:

```
select id, (name || ' ' || surname || ' ' || age) as info from users
```

It should be the key just above the Enter key on a full keyboard, but on mine it's not a sold line - there's a break in the middle of it.  You have to hold the Shift key to get the character (called a pipe, btw).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the ANSI standard concatenation operator is: ||

```
SELECT id, name ||' ' || surname || ' ' || age  AS info FROM users
```

Comment: :) I am writing the answer while you have posted yours one. You can see the difference of 50 sec.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **mysql** or **oracle** then try [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, ' ', surname, ' ', age) as info FROM users
```

Answer (score 2):

It perfectly might be dependent of the database I would take a look for a concatenation function for the database you are running the select for.

Example. Mysql: CONCAT(name, surname, age).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to cast the fields to a common type before concatenating. In T-SQL for example this would read.

```
Select id, Cast(name as varchar(50)) + ' ' + Cast(surname as varchar(50)) + ' ' + 
     Cast(age as varchar(3)) As info From Users
```

Answer (score 2):

|| is used for this purpose.

Use it like 
select name ||' ' ||surname ||' ' ||age as info from users

Answer (score 1):

That should work as is, but in general it is better not to do too much concatenation sql side if you can help it; rather return all the columns and concat them on the other end.

What are the data types you are using?  You may need to `CAST` / `CONVERT` into (n)varchar

Comment: I disagree.  I prefer to have as much manipulation done inside the result set rather than adding code to the application.

Comment: @Larry - doesn't that kind of lock you into the concatenated data?  What if I decide I want to list things as Surname, Name (Age).  Now I have to either write a new query/sproc or parse the string.  For me the database is mainly for data storage and access and very little data manipulation.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, but the alternative is that you need to concatenate the strings in every codebase connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your data types are similar and convert any datatypes to string as necessary:

```
select id, (name + ' ' + surname + ' ' + convert(varchar(3),age)) as info from users
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in most databases I know, although you probably have to CAST the age field to be TEXT.  The exact method for doing this depends on the database you're using, which you did not specify.

Comment: Ugh, that's another reason why I like Oracle more than SQL Server - implicit datatype conversion.